# I need to read a CSV file without using built-in CSV parser in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So I'm doing this project but I need to read the CSV file without using pythons built-in CSV parser. Any ideas of how I could do this?

Comment: read `with open(YOURFILE)` and  `split(FIELD_DELIMITER)` is a good start for you

Comment: Is the file just comma separated or is it actially CSV format?

Comment: comma separated

Answer (score 0):

file need be in the same directory, try this for loop, will read all lines if txt is a simple comma separated

```
f = open (‘myfile.csv’, 'r')

for line in f:
    print (line, end = ‘’)

f.close()
```

Please give me your vote I need it!

Comment: your code will read all lines unconditionally; it doesn't mention comma-separated at all

Comment: @haifeng-zhang already explain to him how to split
"read with open(YOURFILE) and split(FIELD_DELIMITER) is a good start for you"
read before comment please